# jQuery: Show textbox on specific condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

When user select United States I show textbox for US city but what if user deselect the United States?

How could I check if there is **United States** selected or not if not the hide City textbox.
[image]
my script is:

```
<tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap">
<label for="countryId">Countries</label>
</td>
<td>
<select id="countryId" onchange="usCity();" multiple="multiple" name="countryId[]">
<option value="1">United States</option>
<option value="2">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="3">Australia</option>
<option value="4">UAE</option>
<option value="5">Denmark</option>
<option value="6">Czech Republic</option>
<option value="7">Brazil</option>
<option value="8">Singapore</option>
<option value="9">Pakistan</option>
<option value="10">Germany</option>
<option value="11">India</option>
<option value="12">SriLanka</option>
<option value="13">UK</option>
<option value="14">Algeria</option>
<option value="15">Andorra</option>
<option value="16">Caneda</option>
<option value="17">HongKong</option>
</select>
</td>
<td valign="top">
</tr>
<tr id="usCitytr" style="display: none;">
<td nowrap="nowrap">
<label for="USCity">US City Name</label>
</td>
<td colspan="3">
<input id="USCity" type="text" value="" name="USCity">
</td>
</tr>

function usCity()
    {
        if ($("#countryId option:selected").text() == 'United States' || $("#countryId option:selected").text() == 'US'){
            $("#usCitytr").show();
        }
    }
```

I thing on each selection I have to get all selected values in array structure and then using loop to find 'US' if found then show 'US City' textbox else hide. For this I used

```
alert($('select#countryId').text());
```

but it returns all values present in combobox. How ever

```
alert($('select#countryId').val());
```

returns only selected value but I need 'US' not the index where 'US' is present because 'US' might be any where.

Comment: I thing on each selection I have to get all selected values in array structure and then using loop to find 'US' if found then show 'US City' textbox else hide. For this I used   alert($('select#countryId').text()); but it returns all values present in combobox. How ever   alert($('select#countryId').val()); returns only selected value but I need 'US' not the index where 'US' is present because 'US' might be any where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<option id="opt_US" value="1">United States</option>


if ($("#opt_US").is(":selected") {
    $("#usCitytr").show();
} else {
    $("#usCitytr").hide();
}
```

Comment: No because user can select more countries. If he select US and UAE my code is fine but if he deselect US then City box should be hide.. 
But your code code hide city box if I select US and then UAE

Comment: You'd better work with ids for your <option>s. Then you can just look at the <option> representing the US and determine if this one is selected or not.

Comment: You can replace if/else with toggle.

Comment: @ coffee_machine: Thanks it is nice piece of code and I am using it but it still wish to make a generic code means not dependent on hard coded ids because Countries list comes from DB table and while populating data it will require extra checks to set id for US. :)

Comment: I don't like toggle. It does not allow to call the code multiple times when the condition hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function usCity()
    {
        if ($("#countryId option:selected").text() == 'United States' || $("#countryId option:selected").text() == 'US'){
            $("#usCitytr").show();
        } else {
            $("#usCitytr").hide();
        }
    }
```